# Win 8 LocalStorage settings not saved

Tags: c#, .net, application-data

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["stupidcrap"] = "test1";
```

and then after restarting the app in Visual Studio:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
Debug.WriteLine(localSettings.Values["stupidcrap"]);
```

it prints nothing (which means the Object is null).

Why does that happen?

When I do it like this:

```
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["stupidcrap"] = "test1";
Debug.WriteLine(localSettings.Values["stupidcrap"]);
```

it prints successfully, but the point of storage is that the values being saved are available after a restart of the app....

Why is the memory/storage/whatever not saving my values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to add a value, you have to call `localSettings.Values.Add("key", "test1")`

I'm using the following class as a settings helper:

```
public class StorageSettingsApplication
{
    public StorageSettingsApplication()
    {
        try
        {
            localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
    ApplicationDataContainer localSettings;
    publicTValue TryGetValueWithDefault<TValue>(string key, TValue defaultvalue)
    {
        TValue value;

        // If the key exists, retrieve the value.
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            value = (TValue)localSettings.Values[key];
        }
        // Otherwise, use the default value.
        else
        {
            value = defaultvalue;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string key, object value)
    {
        bool valueChanged = false;

        // If the key exists
        //if (localSettings.Contains(Key))
        if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            // If the value has changed
            if (localSettings.Values[key] != value)
            {
                // Store the new value
                localSettings.Values[key] = value;
                valueChanged = true;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise create the key.
        else
        {
            localSettings.Values.Add(key, value);
            valueChanged = true;
        }

        return valueChanged;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks that works.
What is weird is that in the tutorials from MSDN, it says to just use it through localSettings.Values["asd"] = value;

Comment: I wasted hours of my life on this exact issue and left feedback on the MSDN web page to ask them to update the page example with the localSettings.Values.Add(key, value) line.

Comment: In my case it still not save settings

Comment: @user3149172 Are you sure? Make sure you don't force close the app when debugging, force closing will discard all changes. This code works perfectly in 6 apps of mine (both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone)

Comment: What this means ? I set the key and then "Suspend and shutdown" in VS. When I run the app next time there aren't any key.

Comment: While I'm using Release it works great - in debug still lose key.

Comment: @user3149172 Not sure how exactly it behaves when debugging. Only know that when closing the app by stopping debugging it doesn't save.